# How to send authorization header with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

How can I send an authentication header with a token via axios.js?
I have tried a few things without success, for example:

```
const header = `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`;
return axios.get(URLConstants.USER_URL, { headers: { header } });
```

Gives me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/accounts/user/. Request header field header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have managed to get it work by setting global default, but I'm guessing this is not the best idea for a single request:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

**Update :**

Cole's answer helped me find the problem. I am using **django-cors-headers middleware** which already handles authorization header by default.

But I was able to understand the error message and fixed an error in my axios request code, which should look like this

```
return axios.get(URLConstants.USER_URL, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${data.token}` } });
```

Answer (score 107):

On non-simple http requests your browser will send a "preflight" request (an OPTIONS method request) first in order to determine what the site in question considers safe information to send (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for the cross-origin policy spec about this).  One of the relevant headers that the host can set in a preflight response is `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.  If any of the headers you want to send were not listed in either the spec's list of whitelisted headers or the server's preflight response, then the browser will refuse to send your request.

In your case, you're trying to send an `Authorization` header, which is not considered one of the universally safe to send headers.  The browser then sends a preflight request to ask the server whether it should send that header.  The server is either sending an empty `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header (which is considered to mean "don't allow any extra headers") or it's sending a header which doesn't include `Authorization` in its list of allowed headers.  Because of this, the browser is not going to send your request and instead chooses to notify you by throwing an error.

Any Javascript workaround you find that lets you send this request anyways should be considered a bug as it is against the cross origin request policy your browser is trying to enforce for your own safety.

***tl;dr*** -  If you'd like to send `Authorization` headers, your server had better be configured to allow it.  Set your server up so it responds to an `OPTIONS` request at that url with an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` header.

Comment: Thank you, Cole! Your answer helped me find the problem. I am using django-cors-headers middleware which already handles authorization header by default. But I was able to understand the error message and fixed an error in my axios request code, which should look like this   `return axios.get(URLConstants.USER_URL, { headers: { Authorization: \`Bearer ${data.token}\` } });`

Comment: You're welcome!  I run into this sort of issue with my APIs all the time.  Just glad I could help you understand the process it has to go through.

Comment: Well fu¢k this i spent the whole night fighting with this axios cors origin issue. If i just found this answer 10 hours ago

Answer (score 99):

This has worked for me:

```js
let webApiUrl = 'example.com/getStuff';
let tokenStr = 'xxyyzz';
axios.get(webApiUrl, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${tokenStr}`} });
```

Comment: There's less details in the answer compared to the above but this is the answer what everyone is looking for when they search google.

Answer (score 86):

Rather than adding it to every request, you can just add it as a default config like so.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`
```

Comment: how do you place this configuration? in the root (index.js, App.js)? Or in a seperate file?

Comment: what if the token is not setup yet?

Comment: You can use that code to import it when it is ready, so that its available before your request.

Answer (score 51):

Try this :

```js
axios.get(
    url,
    {headers: {
        "name" : "value"
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
      var response = response.data;
    },
    (error) => {
      var status = error.response.status
    }
  );
```

Comment: So header name will be 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' and value is what you want.

Comment: So, you mean I'd have something like: axios.get( url, { headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Bearer <my token>'  } } ) ? That doesn't work.

Comment: I believe it should be { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <my token>' }

Comment: The first comment is incorrect; `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a *response* header and must be sent from the server to the browser. @JohnHarding has it correct; the appropriate header to set *in a request* is an Authorization header. Also, headers which do not have spaces or other special characters do not need to be quoted. Since the question pertains specifically to the Authorization header, and this provides only general advice with only "Try this" by way of explanation, I cannot in good faith upvote it.

Answer (score 9):

You are nearly correct, just adjust your code this way

```
const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
return axios.get(URLConstants.USER_URL, { headers });
```

notice where I place the backticks, I added ' ' after Bearer, you can omit if you'll be sure to handle at the server-side

Comment: Normally (by spec) there is a space, not dash (`-`), between the auth scheme and the token. I've never seen any type of server require a dash as you've shown, and most if not all would send back an error if provided one.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of calling axios.get function Use:

```
axios({ method: 'get', url: 'your URL', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
```

Comment: this helped me realised i put the body into the config. what a rookie mistake. thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
const response=await axios(url,
    method:"GET"
    {
     headers: {
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
axios.get(
    url,
    {headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Content-type": "Application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${your-token}`
            }   
        }
  )
  .then((response) => {
      var response = response.data;
    },
    (error) => {
      var status = error.response.status
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

create a new axios instace for your request

```
  const instance=axios.create({
    baseURL:'www.google.com/'
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'Acess-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                    'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Accept': "application/json"
        }
    })

await instance.get(url,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the `cors` middleware. We were trying to solve it with our own code, but all attempts failed miserably.

This made it work:

```js
cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

[Original link](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/)

Comment: this is for node servers, not for axios

Comment: Users finding this question can find this answer useful.  This question can be used for working with node servers in use cases, and be a reminderthat cors can solve their issue, or to move their backend header check below the above code.  Helped save me so much frustration, Thank you ringing-bell.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Postman way of doing it:

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from('username:password').toString('base64')}`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,OPTIONS,Accept,Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
```

> Blockquote
>   : you have to add OPTIONS & Authorization to the setHeader()

this change has fixed my problem, just give a try!

Comment: This should mention that this must be done in **server code**, not in axios, in order to work.