# How to force axios GET request to send headers?

Tags: vue.js, axios, lumen

Even though my code is inside one of my components in Vue, the problem is with Axios, let me explain why. So, I'm trying to get some information, like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8181/roles/1',  
  {
    headers: {
      'Api-Token': 'tokenTOKEN',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)
.then(response => {console.log(response)})
.catch(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

So, yes, I'm importing Axios correctly. Yes, I know we should not be sending a Content-Type header in a GET request. However, I already read the RFC 7231 and it doesn't say is impossible, is just not common. So, we want to send a Content-Type header in my request.

So, how do I know it doesn't work? Well, one of my middlewares in my Lumen API goes like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class JsonVerifier
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->isJson())
        {
            return $response = $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use Postman to send that specific GET request, and it works. I tried to use `fetch()` like this:

```
var miInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: {
                 'Api-Token': 'tokenTOKEN',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             mode: 'cors',
             cache: 'default' };

fetch('http://localhost:8181/roles/1',miInit)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
```

and it works! In both cases (with Postman and `fetch()`) my API returns the desire data.

However, when I try with Axios, I get a 401 response with the "Unauthorized" word, meaning that Axios didn't send the header correctly.

Now, the question. Is there any other way to send headers in an axios GET request? How can I force Axios to send the headers no matter what as it seem to be case with `fetch()` and Postman?

Comment: You're sending a GET request. It'll never **be** JSON. Have you considers the `Accepts` header and `$request->wantsJson()` function instead, which is what's actually intended for this scenario?

Comment: You should be able to it similar to how `fetch` does it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916965/10431732

Comment: @MattOestreich Nope. Axios (correctly) prevents this in the case of a `Content-Type` header and a data-less request like a `GET` or an empty `POST`. https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/2ee3b482456cd2a09ccbd3a4b0c20f3d0c5a5644/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L112

Comment: @ceejayoz - ahh I read the question too quickly - I thought it was stripping all of the headers... Makes perfect sense to me why they would strip it, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios automatically ([as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)) removes the `Content-Type` header if you're sending a request without a body, as you do with any `GET` request.

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/2ee3b482456cd2a09ccbd3a4b0c20f3d0c5a5644/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L112

```
// Add headers to the request
if ('setRequestHeader' in request) {
  utils.forEach(requestHeaders, function setRequestHeader(val, key) {
    if (typeof requestData === 'undefined' && key.toLowerCase() === 'content-type') {
      // Remove Content-Type if data is undefined
      delete requestHeaders[key];
    } else {
      // Otherwise add header to the request
      request.setRequestHeader(key, val);
    }
  });
}
```

You're probably looking for the `Accepts` header and `$request->wantsJson()` (or `acceptsJson()`) instead.