# Django rest_framework put method doesn't obtain HTTP_AUTHORIZATION

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, jwt

I'm having problems with Django Rest Framework.
When I'm trying to send my JWT token from React with Axios, it sent nothing... The code works for POST and GET but in PUT ... -_-

The settings :

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)
```

Axios call (The token is good, so i don't sending undefined, tested):

```
try {
    console.log("Ejecutando caso Exitoso");
    const response = await axios.put("http://localhost:8000/empresas/empresa-persona/" + param[1], {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Django function (the same function works in GET and POST , but in PUT, HTTP_AUTHORIZATION doesn't exist):

```
def user_call_validation(request, perm):
    # Control de Acceso
    print(request.META)
    user = validate_user_token(token=request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"])
    
        # print(User.objects.get(id=user["id"]).get_all_permissions())
    if User.objects.get(id=user["id"]).has_perm(perm) != True:
        raise Exception("Acceso denegado!")
```

Comment: are you sure this is a django problem? check this question out It seems that axios get and put have different syntax for setting headers [Why is this axios put request not setting the headers peoperly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539518/why-is-this-axios-put-request-not-setting-the-headers-peoperly)