# How do i pass in a header from axios before a accessing a controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios, laravel-8, laravel-9

is there a way to inject axios.get() header into a route request before the controller is accessed.

Please not that a link with the url (/verify) was sent to the users email via api and i want to include the bearer token then the user clicks the url.

This is my route from web.php

```
    Route::get('/verify-email', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
```

And this is create in a js folder

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.create({
  baseURL: '/verify-email',
  headers: {'Bearer Token': 'foobar515615612655'}
});
```

Comment: axios.create({
  baseURL: '/verify-email',
  headers: {'Bearer': 'foobar515615612655'}
});

This should be Bearer instead of Bearer Token if its not working check it with axios.post request with headers: {'Bearer': 'foobar515615612655'}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send authorization header with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245588/how-to-send-authorization-header-with-axios)

Comment: @ManishJ That's not how you send the `authorization` header. `Bearer` is part of the header value, not its key.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the `x-requested-with` header with `XMLHttpRequest` as value.

Checkout the following example:

```
headers: {
  'Bearer Token': 'foobar515615612655',
  'x-requested-with' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
```